# Clarity Datagrid server-side binding with custom filter (code optimization)

Tags: angular, vmware-clarity, clarity

I am trying to optimize my code that utilizes Clarity datagrid with server-side binding and some custom actions(e.g.,
a custom filter, similar to [Datagrid Enhancement: Filtering](https://github.com/vmware/clarity/issues/1632)) and a refresh button that refetches grid data and makes additional calls).

This is the current workflow:

- Initial load

  - datagridRefresh()

    - refresh()

      - additionalCalls()
      - dispatchFilterRequestPromise()
- Custom refresh button

  - refresh()

    - additionalCalls()
    - dispatchFilterRequestPromise()
- Paging

  - datagridRefresh()

    - dispatchFilterRequestPromise()
- Custom filtering

  - filterChange()

    - $(".pagination-first").click()

      - datagridRefresh()

        - dispatchFilterRequestPromise()
    - (or) dispatchFilterRequestPromise()

gridView.html:

```html
<button (click)="refresh()"
    global refresh
</button>
<clr-datagrid #dataGrid
              (clrDgRefresh)="datagridRefresh($event)">
  ...
    <clr-dg-row *ngFor="let dataItem of dataItems" [clrDgItem]="dataItem">
  ... 
   <clr-dg-footer>
      <clr-dg-pagination #pagination
                         [clrDgTotalItems]="total"
                         [hidden]="!total"
                         [clrDgPageSize]="DEFAULT_ITEMS_PER_PAGE">
...
      </clr-dg-pagination>
   </clr-dg-footer>
</clr-datagrid>

<cross-column-filter (changes)="filterChange($event);"
                          [filters]="filters">
</cross-column-filter>
```

gridView.component.ts:

```js
dataItems: MyItem[];
readonly DEFAULT_ITEMS_PER_PAGE: number = 20;
private static readonly DEFAULT_START_INDEX: number = 0;

ngOnInit() {
  if (hasPredefinedFilters) {
     this.filters = this.predefinedFilters;
  }
  this.refreshSubscription = this.refreshSubject
        .subscribe(async (state: ClrDatagridStateInterface) => {
           await this.dispatchFilterRequestPromise(state);
        });
}

filterChange(filters: FilterItem[]) {
  this.filters = filters;
  // If total is changed to a smaller value when the current page is > 1, the clrDgRefresh event is fired which
  // leads to an additional request.
  // The following code solves that and ensures the current page is 1 when applying filter.
  if (this.state && this.state.page && this.state.page.from &&
        this.state.page.from > gridView.DEFAULT_START_INDEX) {
     $(".pagination-first").click();
  } else {
     this.refreshSubject.next(this.state);
  }
}


refresh() {
    this.additionalCalls();
    this.dispatchFilterRequestPromise(this.state);
}

additionalCalls() {
...
}


datagridRefresh(state: ClrDatagridStateInterface) {
  // Remember the last state to use it again when the global refresh button is clicked
  this.state = state;
  // clrDgRefresh event is fired on initial load and each filtering/paging operation.
  // It's not needed to fetch data on initial grid load because this is done when global refresh handler is attached.
  if (this.gridFirstRefresh) {
     this.gridFirstRefresh = false;
     this.refresh();
  } else {
     this.loading = true;
     this.refreshSubject.next(state);
  }
}

dispatchFilterRequestPromise = (state: ClrDatagridStateInterface): Promise<void> => {

  const requestFilters: MyFilterSpec = this.createRequestFilters(state);
  if (requestFilters) {
    this.dataService.getDataItems(ManagedObject.contextObject, requestFilters).then(result => {
        this.dataItems = result.dataItems;
        this.total = result.total;});
  } else {
     this.dataItems = [];
     this.total = 0;
     return null;
  }
};
```

- I have a flag in clrDgRefresh(i.e.,datagridRefresh) to differentiate between initial load and subsequent calls. I see that there is a bug related to avoid triggering clrDgRefresh on initial load ([clr-datagrid should not call clr-dgRefresh when it gets Destroyed/Initialized](https://github.com/vmware/clarity/issues/1099)). If the bug is resolved I can move the code inside that flag to onInit event but I see that the issue has been opened 2 years ago and not sure whether there is any progress on it.
- The other question is related to triggering custom filter update (i.e., filterChange()).

  - Generally, if total is changed to a smaller value when the current page is > 1, the clrDgRefresh event is fired which leads to an additional request. Is this an issue ?
  - If the above condition is met I click programmatically on the first page to trigger clrDgRefresh otherwise call dispatchFilterRequestPromise(). Is there a better approach to handle that ?
    I see there are some issues related to binding the filter ([[NG] Ability to set the state of a datagrid with a single input](https://github.com/vmware/clarity/issues/2094) and [Add [(clrDgFiltered)] to expose items in Datagrid matching current filters](https://github.com/vmware/clarity/issues/253)) that if implemented may improve the current code.
- I wondered whether having a client-side binding with custom pager would make the code look more clear than the current approach.

Answer (score 1):

Clarity Datagrid automatically calls `clrDgRefresh` if you start using this binding. There is no way to handle/avoid these calls. However, if we add a debounce before the function `datagridRefresh()` then we can control it using a flag. Please check out this [stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/clarity-datagrid-clrdgrefresh-issue-fix)

Secondly, there is also one [issue](https://github.com/vmware/clarity/issues/1099) with using `clrDgRefresh`, it does not get destroyed immediately on `ngDestroy` of the corresponding component and hence it calls the handler multiple times on route change event. Again, this issue can be fixed via the same workaround as mentioned above (refer to the stackblitz)